# Regex: Exclude capturing a pattern which may or may not be present

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a few variations of similar strings:

```
#This is a string
#This is another string (with some info in parentheses)
```

I want to run them all through a Regex and capture `"#This"` in the first capture group, and `"a string"` or `"another string"` in the second capture group.

Notice in the second string I don't want the parentheses' or its content.

I've tried a bunch or Regexes that give the following outputs

`/#(.*) is (.*)/`: simplest regex, but doesn't exclude the parentheses and its contents

```
String1 Match1:     This
String1 Match2:     a string
String2 Match1:     This
String2 Match2:     another string (with some info in parentheses)
```

`/#(.*) is (.*)\(/` adding an opening parentheses works only for string that actually has it

```
String1 Match1:     null
String1 Match2:     null
String2 Match1:     This
String2 Match2:     another string
```

`/#(.*) is (.*)\(*/` making it optional with a `*` (this is incorrect I guess)

```
String1 Match1:     This
String1 Match2:     a string
String2 Match1:     This
String2 Match2:     another string (with some info in parentheses)
```

`/#(.*) is (.*)\(?/` making it optional with a `?` (same result)

```
String1 Match1:     This
String1 Match2:     a string
String2 Match1:     This
String2 Match2:     another string (with some info in parentheses)
```

`/#(.*) is (.*?)\(*/` making it non-greedy

```
String1 Match1:     This
String1 Match2:     null
String2 Match1:     This
String2 Match2:     null
```

```js
var string1 = "#This is a string";
var string2 = "#This is another string (with some info in parentheses)";

// var regex = /#(.*) is (.*)/;
// var regex = /#(.*) is (.*)\(/;
// var regex = /#(.*) is (.*)\(*/;
   var regex = /#(.*) is (.*)\(?/;
// var regex = /#(.*) is (.*?)\(*/;

var match1 = string1.match(regex);
var match2 = string2.match(regex);

alert('String1 Match1: \t' + ((match1&&match1[1])?match1[1]:'null') + '\nString1 Match2: \t' + ((match1&&match1[2])?match1[2]:'null') +
    '\nString2 Match1: \t' + ((match2&&match2[1])?match2[1]:'null') + '\nString2 Match2: \t' + ((match2&&match2[2])?match2[2]:'null') );
```

Comment: Another solution `/#(.*) is ([^\(\)]*)/` (posted by someone who deleted, but I like it as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make any symbol or group (including) opening parentheses optional you need to use ? (question mark), not * (star).
You need to stop on ( or end of line which come first so maybe You need somethink like `/#(.*) is (.*?)(\(|$)/m`

Comment: Works great, except one thing -'#' is not captured, or i am missing something?

Comment: It's not inside any of captures group. Same as it was in the question. May be you need to include it to first group /(#.*) is (.*?)(\(|$)/m

Comment: just a tip: you can create NON-CAPTURE-groups which doesn't affect result but are for grouping like "(?:  )"